# Can run class c++ in Visual Studio but not in VSCode. Is this normal?

Tags: c++

i'm a beginner in c/c++ programmation, i've been learning for 1 year. What i'm trying to do is a matrix class in a header file. It works perfectly fine on Microsoft Visual Studio but doesn't on VSCode, any idea why ? (I would like to make it work on VSCode since i use it more than Visual Studio).

Here's the code :

```
#define _MATRIX_

// Includes
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

// Uses
using namespace std;

// Templates
template <class T>

// Constants

// const int rows = 10;
// const int columns = 10;

class Matrix {
private: // Private class members are only available within matrix.cpp.
    int rows, columns;
    T* matrix;
public: // Public class members are available outside of the matrix class.

// Constructor
    Matrix(int Rows, int Columns) {
        rows = Rows;
        columns = Columns;

        matrix = new T[rows * columns];
    }

    Matrix(int Size) {
        rows = Size;
        columns = Size;

        matrix = new T[Size * Size];
    }

    Matrix(const Matrix& pmatrix) {
        rows = pmatrix.rows;
        columns = pmatrix.columns;

        matrix = new T[pmatrix.rows * pmatrix.columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++) {
            matrix[i] = pmatrix.matrix[i];
        }
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Matrix() {
        delete[] matrix;
    }

    // Iostream Operators

    friend istream& operator>> <> (istream& s, Matrix& pmatrix);
    friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& s, const Matrix& pmatrix);

};

template <typename M>
istream& operator>> (istream& s, Matrix<M>& pmatrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pmatrix.rows * pmatrix.columns; i++) {
        s >> pmatrix.matrix[i];
    }
    return s;
}

template <typename M>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, const Matrix<M>& pmatrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pmatrix.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pmatrix.columns; j++) {
            s << pmatrix.matrix[i * pmatrix.columns + j] << " ";
        }
        s << endl;
    }
    return s;
}

#endif // _MATRIX_
```

Here's the .cpp :

```
int main() {
    ifstream fin("input.txt");

    Matrix<int> A(2, 3);

    fin >> A;
    cout << A << endl;

    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Finally here are the error codes i'm getting from VSCode :

```
Matrix.h: In instantiation of 'class Matrix<int>':
Matrix.cpp:6:15:   required from here
Matrix.h:59:18: error: template-id 'operator>><>' for 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Matrix<int>&)' does not match any template declaration
  friend istream& operator>> <> (istream& s, Matrix& pmatrix);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\fstream:38:0,
                 from Matrix.h:5,
                 from Matrix.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:924:5: note: candidates are: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, _Tp&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __is, _Tp& __x)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:808:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:803:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)      
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:761:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)        
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char& __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:756:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char& __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:934:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from Matrix.h:5,
                 from Matrix.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc:923:5: note:                 template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT& __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc:955:5: note:                 template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:53:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from Matrix.h:5,
                 from Matrix.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc:1437:5: note:                 template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from Matrix.cpp:1:0:
Matrix.h:60:18: error: template-id 'operator<< <>' for 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix<int>&)' does not match any template declaration
  friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& s, const Matrix& pmatrix);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from Matrix.h:5,
                 from Matrix.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:628:5: note: candidates are: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:574:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const unsigned char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:569:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const signed char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:556:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:638:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from Matrix.h:5,
                 from Matrix.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\ostream.tcc:321:5: note:                 template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from Matrix.h:5,
                 from Matrix.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:539:5: note:                 template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const _CharT*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const _CharT* __s)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:519:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, unsigned char __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:514:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, signed char)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, signed char __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:508:5: note:                 template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:502:5: note:                 template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:497:5: note:                 template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, _CharT __c)
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:46:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from Matrix.h:5,
                 from Matrix.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\system_error:209:5: note:                 template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::error_code&)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, const error_code& __e)
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:52:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\fstream:38,
                 from Matrix.h:5,
                 from Matrix.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:5325:5: note:                 template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from Matrix.cpp:1:0:
Matrix.h: In instantiation of 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Matrix<M>&) [with M = int; std::istream = std::basic_istream<char>]':
Matrix.cpp:8:9:   required from here
Matrix.h:66:30: error: 'int Matrix<int>::rows' is private within this context
  for (int i = 0; i < pmatrix.rows * pmatrix.columns; i++) {
                      ~~~~~~~~^~~~
Matrix.h:22:6: note: declared private here
  int rows, columns;
      ^~~~
Matrix.h:66:45: error: 'int Matrix<int>::columns' is private within this context
  for (int i = 0; i < pmatrix.rows * pmatrix.columns; i++) {
                                     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
Matrix.h:22:12: note: declared private here
  int rows, columns;
            ^~~~~~~
Matrix.h:67:16: error: 'int* Matrix<int>::matrix' is private within this context
   s >> pmatrix.matrix[i];
        ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
Matrix.h:23:5: note: declared private here
  T* matrix;
     ^~~~~~
Matrix.h: In instantiation of 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix<M>&) [with M = int; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]':
Matrix.cpp:9:10:   required from here
Matrix.h:74:30: error: 'int Matrix<int>::rows' is private within this context
  for (int i = 0; i < pmatrix.rows; i++) {
                      ~~~~~~~~^~~~
Matrix.h:22:6: note: declared private here
  int rows, columns;
      ^~~~
Matrix.h:75:31: error: 'int Matrix<int>::columns' is private within this context
   for (int j = 0; j < pmatrix.columns; j++) {
                       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
Matrix.h:22:12: note: declared private here
  int rows, columns;
            ^~~~~~~
Matrix.h:76:17: error: 'int* Matrix<int>::matrix' is private within this context
    s << pmatrix.matrix[i * pmatrix.columns + j] << " ";
         ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
Matrix.h:23:5: note: declared private here
  T* matrix;
     ^~~~~~
Matrix.h:76:36: error: 'int Matrix<int>::columns' is private within this context
    s << pmatrix.matrix[i * pmatrix.columns + j] << " ";
                            ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
Matrix.h:22:12: note: declared private here
  int rows, columns;
            ^~~~~~~
```

And finally to prove that it works on Visual Studio : [Debug Console Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8heY6.png)

I don't need to explain what's in input.txt, right ? Just in case there's :

- 1 2 3
- 4 5 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this...

```
friend istream& operator>> <> (istream& s, Matrix& pmatrix);
friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& s, const Matrix& pmatrix);
```

Is it the case that VS is set up for c++14 but MinGW (that you're using with VS-Code) is C++11?  You might need to declare the C++ standard on the compiler command line `-std=c++14`

Alternatively look at how to use `cl` with VSCode instead of MinGW:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. My Visual Studio runs C++14 C++17 and C++latest. I can't seem to find which c++ version MinGW uses. I've tried adding -std=c++14 in the compiler command line as such : cd "c:\Users\Nobunaji\source\repos\matrix\Matrix\" ; if ($?) { g++ Matrix.cpp -std=c++14 -o Matrix } ; if ($?) { .\Matrix } I might have made an error so correct me if i did. Meanwhile i will try to configure msvc. Thank you.